# How to import CSV / Excel data into wordpress custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, import, wpallimport

scenario:

I have custom post type named product.product post type have custom fields which is created using ACF(Advanced Custom Field).

i have data of 400+ products. i want to import that data in to product post type.

i used WP all import. it is importing only post title and category, it is not importing custom fields.

Answer (score -1):

Use Plugin wp-all-import the one best plugin to do that. Although you can do it by custom php code also.

Comment: i tried WP all import. it is not importing the ACF (Advanced Custom Field) it is only importing Title,Category and Content.  i am selecting the custom field values still it is not importing.
i also tried to import it using update_post_meta(), it is working but i have to update the the post from the wordpress admin. for example: 
i open some post the values are there in the textfield but it is not dsiplaying on the frontend. if i update that post then it is displaying